# Handle Accents & Accented Characters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, encoding

I have to handle these Strings that go inside an Alert that pops up when the user fails to Login.

This is how it looks like now

```
FaultCode : Faltou informar o usuÃ¡rio!
FaultCode : Campo obrigatÃ³rio
```

And this is how it should be:

```
FaultCode : Faltou informar o usuário! 
FaultCode : Campo obrigatório
```

Here is the UIAlertAction I'm using:

```
 let loginAlert = UIAlertController(title:faultActor, message: faultString, preferredStyle: .alert)
 let acaoDefault = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:  .destructive, handler: nil)
 loginAlert.addAction(acaoDefault)
 present(loginAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And here is the function I wrote to handle the response:
manageFaultMessage is a function that handles the Fault Message from my Web Service.

```
func manageFaultMessage(faultMessage: XMLIndexer, requestName: String) throws {
        //Fault SOAP Message
        let faultXML = faultMessage["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"]["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["SOAP-ENV:Fault"]

        if faultXML.children.count > 0 {
            guard let faultCode: String = faultXML["faultcode"].element?.text else {
                throw XMLParseError.UnknownField
            }

            guard let faultActor: String = faultXML["faultactor"].element?.text else {
                throw XMLParseError.UnknownField
            }

            guard let faultString: String = faultXML["faultstring"].element?.text else {
                throw XMLParseError.UnknownField
            }
            guard let detail: String = faultXML["detail"].element?.text else {
                throw XMLParseError.UnknownField
            }
            self.delegate.didFaultRequest(faultCode: faultCode, faultActor: faultActor, faultString: faultString, detail: detail, requestName: nomeServico)
        } else {

            throw XMLParseError.EmptyXML
        }
    }
```

Now where should I add the encoding and how?

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. The strings you've given don't have accents in them. I presume they're incorrectly encoded ("usuÃ¡rio!") What encoding is your web service sending you? It's very unclear what we're supposed to make of `manageFaultMessage()`. What do you expect your code to do (precisely), and what does it actually do (precisely)?

Comment: I edited it. What I need is to know how I can encode the response from my Web Services. manageFaultMessage() is how I handle the the response from a failed login attempt. @RobNapier

Comment: What character encoding is your web service using? How are you decoding the values you receive? You don't show how `faultMessage` is constructed or what an `XMLIndexer` is. Somewhere it turns bytes into a string. What encoding does it use to do that? Is it the same encoding that the server is using?

Comment: (Just to give you a place to go looking, this particular encoding mistake usually means someone used Latin-1, also called ISO_8859-1, or possibly ASCII, rather than UTF-8.)